# Express + PassportJs : Why do we need to delay the execution of method with process.nextTick() in passport strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport local strategy for user registration. I came across this code example where author is using process.nextTick to delay the execution of a method inside Passport LocalStrategy callback. I understand that we can delay the execution of some method with process.nextTick and execute it in the next tick of the event loop but can you explain me why do we need to use it in this example?

```
passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) {

    findOrCreateUser = function() {
        if (isValidEmail(email)) {
            // find a user in Mongo with provided email
            User.findOne({
                'email': email
            }, function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error in SignUp: ' + err);
                    return done(err);
                }
                // already exists
                if (user) {
                    console.log('User already exists with email: ' + email);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Already Exists'));
                } else {
                    // if there is no user with that email
                    // create the user
                    var newUser = new User();

                    // set the user's local credentials
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.password = createHash(password);

                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
                            throw err;
                        }
                        console.log('User Registration succesful');
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Not a valid Email!');
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Email!'));
        }
    }

    // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
    // in the next tick of the event loop
    process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because the author wants to keep the function always asynchronous. In the code snippet, if `isValidEmail(user)` returns false, this code is synchronous ( since it doesn't include any io operation). By delaying the execution, the error handler is called next tick so that this handle is always asynchronous no matter the email is valid or not.